# What techniques do JavaScript compression libraries use to minimize file size?

Tags: javascript, optimization, theory

Please note that this question is intended to be a bit more on the theory side of the subject, but besides stripping whitespace what other techniques are used for [JavaScript Compression](http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the compressors use a combination of different techniques:

- stripping whitespaces
- compress file by compression algorythm (gzip, deflate)
- most of the space is saved renaming interall variables and function to shorter names, eg:

This function:

```
function func (variable) {
  var temp = 2 * variable;
  return temp;
}
```

will become:

```
function func (a) {
  var b = 2 * a;
  return b;
}
```

- Dean Edwards [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) uses some internal compression. The script is decompressed whhen loaded on the page.
- All the usual stuff to make a programmcode shorter:

  - delete unused code
  - function inlining

Comment: Will become: function f(a){return 2*a;} ;) from 72 chars down to 27

Comment: if you want to use func on global javascript scope i would leave the name as it is... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head...

- Tokenizes local variables and then renames them to a minimally-sized variable.
- Removes tons of whitespace.
- Removes unnecessary braces (for example, single line executions after if-statements can remove braces and add a single semi-colon).
- Removes unnecessary semi-colons (for example, right before an ending brace '}').

My most commonly used minifier is the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), and [as they state](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#work), it's open source so you can take a look for yourself on exactly what they do.  (I'm not sure what they mean by "micro-optimizations", probably a bunch of rare cases that gain you a character or two.)

Answer (score 0):

I can name a few that are found within Google Web Toolkit compiler:

- Inline of method calls
- Dead Code elimination
- Variable renaming/source obfuscation

  - this means rewriting long variables to short ones and so on

Almost all of them require Javascript parsing (ie they work beyond a pure lexical analysis).

Comment: That dead code part scares me, how does GWT know that code is dead when JS has a global scope?  Or is GWT designed for compiling all your JS at once, and doesn't work if you execute it on only one of your multiple JS files?

Comment: GWT is a monolithic compiler, so by adding some restrictions to what you can do within java, it can accurately determine if a method is called or not (similar to what you can do with eclipse ide).

Answer (score 0):

Code renaming and reordering so that gzip compressor will have better result.

for example (not so clever)

original code:

```
function mul(mul1, mul2)
{
 return mul1 * mul2;
}

function print(str)
{
  // do something 
}

function add(add1, add2)
{
 return add1 + add2;
}
```

modify code:

```
function mul(a,b)
{
 return a * b;
}

function add(a, b)
{
 return a + b;
}

function print(str)
{
  // do something 
}
```

Comment: I'm down voting this answer as you didn't really answer the question, namely what *techniques* are being used.

Comment: sorry Rob, I didn't read the entire question. 
New answer, hope I do better this time :)

Comment: It's just a sample to the idea, of course that you can preform only operation that won't affect the result.